probability distribution for "most recent k partners"
I'm trying to infer rates of partnerships forming / ending within a population stratified into groups. The challenge: we only have data* for the most recent $k=3$ partners for any given individual. *The data: group memberships, partnership duration, and if the partnership is ongoing. Here is what I have so far:
Notation:

Let $N_i$ be the population size of group $i$
Let $f_{ij}$ be the mean per-person rate of partnerships formed by individuals in group $i$ with those in group $j$.

Then $F_{ij} = f_{ij} N_i = f_{ji} N_j$ is the total rate of partnerships forming at the population level, which is symmetric (though $f_{ij}$ is not).
Also $p_{ij} = f_{ij}/\sum_{j}f_{ij}$ is the conditional probability of a group-$i$ individual forming a given partnership with group $j$.


Let $d_{ij}$ be the mean duration of partnerships among groups $i$ and $j$ (which must be symmetric).

Then $X_{ij} = f_{ij} d_{ij}$ is the expected number of ongoing partnerships with $j$ for each individual in group $i$.


Let $g$ be the total number of ongoing partnerships for a given individual.
Let $\theta_{ij,k}$ be the probability of a group-$i$ individual reporting their $k$-th most recent partner as group $j$.

Assume: individuals with $g > 0$ ongoing partnerships will report all these as most recent first (random order if $g > 1$), followed by $k-g$ other partnerships which ended most recently.



Objective: Derive an expression for $\theta_{ij,k}$ from $f_{ij}, d_{ij}, k$.
Progress: Consider 3 cases for a given individual ...

If $g \ge k$ (all ongoing), then:
$$ \theta_{ij} = \frac{X_{ij}}{\sum_j X_{ij}} $$

If $g = 0$ (none ongoing), then:
$$ \theta_{ij} = \frac{f_{ij}}{\sum_j f_{ij}} = p_{ij} $$

If $0 < g < k$ (some but not all ongoing), then ... I'm stuck. From simulation, it seems this part of $\theta_{ij,k}$ will actually depend on $k$.


ps, we can assume steady-state / infinite time.
